# How to bring activity to front with using ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED

Tags: android, nfc

I am making a project and I want that my application comes foreground when it detects an ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED tag. I can do bringing foreground process via a service, but I want that, my applications can listen NFC even it is in the background, and if it is in the background comes foreground by itself.

Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

Youre interested in filtering for NFC intents. Its a mechanism that allows you to launch your app when a tag is detected. Also, check out disabling/enanbling foreground dispatch.